# How to call put_items async in python dynamodb, if write function and dynamodb initialization are in separated functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, python-asyncio

Newbie to python here. I am changing some code which handles dynamodb write from sync to async, to reduce the latency. Current source code uses `boto3` to connect to dynamodb:

```
import boto3


"""
Create dynamodb connection
"""
def _create_dynamo_connection(self):
   dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
   return dynamodb 


"""
Write to dynamodb
"""
def _write_to_dynamodb(self, dynamodb, data):
   table = dynamodb.Table(DYNAMODB_TABLE)
   data_entry = json.loads(json.dumps(data))
   # The put_item takes time and we would want to execute the write step without wait
   aws_response = table.put_item(Item=data_entry)
```

In order to make the write function from synchronous to asynchronous approach, initially I was thinking of using `aioboto3` ([lib](https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/)) replacing `boto3`, but after seeing the example code, it seems like the dynamodb is created with `with` clause and cannot be returned. This makes the syntax very different from the current

```
import asyncio
import aioboto3


async def main():
    session = aioboto3.Session()
    async with session.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-central-1') as dynamo_resource:
        table = await dynamo_resource.Table('test_table')

        await table.put_item(
            Item={'pk': 'test1', 'col1': 'some_data'}
        )
```

I am wondering: if the only need is to make the "write" async, can I just make minor modification of the `_write_to_dynamodb()` method? Will I be able to have a workaround without the `aioboto3` but with `asyncio`. If so, what will the syntax look like?

Comment: If you don’t use aioboto3, you won’t be able to await `table.put_item`.

Comment: @dirn thanks. I was also wondering if I can get around by just using library `asyncio` ?

Comment: I think you’d be doing yourself a disservice by not using libraries that know how to speak to AWS for you, but sure, you could do it without a third party library. I just wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: @dirn the reason I am a little concerned about using `aioboto3` is that for each write operation, it requires a new connection (or session), which is different from what I currently have. The thought of breaking the existing logic into separate functions is to use the same dynamodb instance already created.

Comment: @jsh6303 you can use `contextlib` for maintaining the session until you manually close it, that is, avoid the `async with` altogether. The author of `aioboto3` has mentioned this solution in one of the issues [here](https://github.com/terrycain/aioboto3/issues/279#issuecomment-1309061484)